# How to achieve pagination in swift stack objects storage (openstack swift)

Tags: openstack-swift

I used the query parameters 'limit', 'marker', and 'end_marker'. The parameter limit with marker works well(url?limit=10&marker=xyz). But How to achieve pagination using limit. Example I want fetch first 10 records and second request another 10 records.
I referred [this](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html#storage_object_services), but there is no range in limit option.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the last record from the previous request as a marker.

First request

```
GET /v1/ACCOUNT/CONTAINER?limit=2

object1
object2
```

Second request

```
GET /v1/ACCOUNT/CONTAINER?limit=2&marker=object2

object3
object4
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. But If the objects(Files) inside the sub directory then it is not working.I want to search files only not a folder

Comment: Openstack Swift doesn't have folders. Everything is an object (file). What you might be seeing is a object which names ends with a slash (object/) or a object with slashes on its name (just-a-name/object.txt). With that in mind, you might filter the response. Perhaps the option "end_marker" can somehow help you. I  hope it helps.